# Quantify compatibility between posterior estimates

Tags: estimation, references, density-function, posterior

I am performing $n$ distinct, independent experiment $E_1$, $E_2$, $\ldots, E_n$ to ideally measure the same quantity $X \in \mathbb{R}$ of interest.
For each experiment, I can compute the posterior pdf of $X$ via MCMC, according to some underlying model, which we call $f_1(x)$, $f_2(x)$, $\ldots, f_n(x)$. There is a chance, hard to quantify and model, that the experiments are *not* measuring the same thing.

What would be the most reasonable/established method to:

- *test* whether the $n$ estimates are compatible (we can focus for simplicity on the case $n =2$);
- and/or *quantify* such compatibility?

For example, as a test I could simply compare the 95% credible intervals (computed via empirical quantiles of the MCMC samples), and check that they all overlap; as a quantitative metric I could perhaps report the percentage of overlap between the 95% CI, or something along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can quantify the difference between probability distributions using the [Earth Mover's distance (EMD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance).

As for testing... assuming that you want to do classical null hypothesis significance testing, you could of course use the EMD as your test statistic. To get its distribution under the null hypothesis, you could simulate your experiments actually measuring the same thing, run your two separate MCMCs, and record the resulting EMD. Do this many times, and you have your EMD null distribution. Finally, compare your "true" EMD to this one.

Comment: (+1) Thanks. I could quantify the difference between pdfs in many ways. What's good about EMD as opposed to (symmetrized) KL divergence or other metrics? (Also, I only have MCMC samples, but I could always compute a histogram.) 
Simulating experiments under the null hypothesis is a good idea, but running MCMCs on a single dataset takes days, so I cannot rerun it many times as part of the testing.

Comment: What I personally like most about the EMD is its ease of interpretability. If you can't reasonably simulate, you will have a hard time doing NHST, because there will likely not be a simple formula for the null distributed distance, whatever distance measure you decide to use. Maybe best just to plot the two histograms (overlaid, or back-to-back), and eyeballing them.